# How do i make my button link to another page, in jquery?

Tags: jquery, button

html

```
<input type="submit" id="submit_button" class="push" value="Complete Registration"</input>
```

js

```
if (this.checked && $("#num_attendees option:selected").text() != 'Please Choose'
    && $.stepTwoComplete_one == 'complete' && $.stepTwoComplete_two == 'complete') {
    $("#submit_button").attr("disabled",false);
} else {
    $("#submit_button").attr("disabled",true);
}
```

Comment: 1) You are closing the input tag wrong. 2) The code seems to have nothing to do with the question. 3) Setting `document.location.href` in JavaScript will make the browser go to another page.

Comment: where about do i set it?

Comment: I have no idea, because I have no idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: i have a button on a forum that needs to take the user to the homepage, which is called homepage.html, any ideas?

Comment: `<button onclick="document.location.href='letsGoOverHereYay.htm'">Woo! Away We Go!</button>`

Comment: it still wont work, thankyou for your help, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest you buy a beginners book on HTML or JavaScript. Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8jZD9/

Comment: it works now thankyou so much! one last question on a form do you know how to make the name they enter on the form, to appear on every other page on the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the submit button wrapped around a form element, and end the submit button tag correctly (as said by Dave):

```
<form action="myScript.php" method="post">
  <input type="submit" id="submit_button" class="push" value="Complete Registration"/>
</form>
```